# Bower not copying files in project folder

Tags: node.js, twitter, npm

I tried [Twitter](http://twitter.com)'s new [`bower`](https://github.com/twitter/bower) tool today, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work as advertised. I'm using Ubuntu and have installed the latest `node.js`. I installed `Node` following the guide on node's github

```
tar -zxf node-v0.8.8.tar.gz #Downloaded this from nodejs.org
cd node-v0.8.8
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and `bower` with this line

```
npm install bower -g
```

Then I created a new folder in my html folder and from there I tried

```
bower install domready
```

Bower then does this

```
bower cloning git://github.com/ded/domready.git
bower caching git://github.com/ded/domready.git
bower fetching domready
bower copying /home/ps/.bower/domready
```

The files then exist in "/home/ps/.bower/domready". The documantation though says the files will be put in "/path/to/project/components/", but the components folder stays empty. Same with

```
sudo bower install domready
```

There's no error/warning/hint/whatsoever appearing. Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please see these edits and ensure that I've followed along with your intent clearly.

Comment: ok, added some changes. thank you!

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, I see bower caching the git repos, but it never copies the items to my project.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Has to be some config problem. I am running bower with yeoman on a windows machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna try a bower init first to create a bower.json file. Afterwards do your installs (with the --save flag) and you will see a components folder with all your js goodies.

Should do the trick